# Arduino Serial.read() not displaying the correct output

Tags: serial-port, arduino, switch-statement

This program I am writing for the arduino to control a couple stepper motors. I read all the data from the serial and put it into an array. Now this works beautifully for the fan, but it pukes when I input a value equal to the second value in the "case" statement. Anything else works fine.

```
i.e.)from serial input: "F"
                 output: "F" and the fan turns on/off
but              input:  "a100" 
                 output: "a1"  and nothing the serial com freezes
```

Aduino Mega 2500 R3:

Arduino IDE 1.0.6

```
 #include <Stepper.h>
 #define FAN_PIN 9                                // the fan is hooked up to pin 9


 const int stepsPerRevolution = 200;              // change this to fit the number of steps per             
 revolution for your motor
 const int RPM = 30;                               // much over thirty is too fast to respond to      
 int step_mode = 4;                               // 4 = full, 8 = half
 int yPosition = 0;                               // number of steps the motor has taken
 byte byte_step;                                  // serial only reads in bytes
 long previous = stepsPerRevolution/2;            // This may come in handy eventually idk
 char dataIn[20];
 char data;
 int step_size[20];
 int count = 0;
 int count_new;
 int i;
 int num_steps = 0;
 boolean neg = false;                            // Default to positive steps
 boolean FAN = false;                            // Default to fan off

 // initialize the stepper library on pins :
 Stepper myStepper(stepsPerRevolution, 60,61,56,57, step_mode);             
 //Stepper(number_of_steps, motor_pin_1, motor_pin_2, motor_pin_3, motor_pin_4)   


void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()>0){
      command = Serial.read();
      while(data != 13) {    
          data = Serial.read();
          if(data == '-') neg = true;                     //    case you receive a negative, defaults to false (positive)
           else{
              dataIn[count] = data;
              Serial.println(count);
              count++;                 // count is NOT!!!!! equal to the number of relevant elements within the array
           delay(1);
     }
  }   

 switch(command){
    case 'F':                                      // case to turn the fan on/off
       if (FAN == false){
           FAN = true;
           analogWrite(FAN_PIN,90);
       }                                          //   WRITE(FAN_PIN, HIGH); PWM because we have a 5V fan on a 12V pin
       else if(FAN == true){
           FAN = false;
           digitalWrite(FAN_PIN,LOW);               //   turn the fan off
       }
       break;

    case 'G':                               // the case of motor "a"       
        for(i=2; count-1; i++){
                 num_steps = num_steps *10 + ;    //convert it to a base 10 number
           }
        break;   
  }                     
  if(neg == true){
      num_steps = num_steps*-1;    // Make it negative then default it back to positive
      neg = false; 
  }
  myStepper.step(num_steps);
  yPosition = yPosition + num_steps;
  Serial.println(yPosition);
  for(i=0; i<20; i++){           //clear out the data
      dataIn[i] = 0;
  }
  count = 0;
  num_steps = 0;
```

}
}

Comment: Time delay is a terribly unreliable way to do synchronization!  Get rid of the delay and collect characters (waiting for availability) until you get a definitive terminating condition - perhaps a newline.  Then parse.

Comment: I never realized that it was wrong to do that. Just read an article about it. I changed the offending code to:                 `    void loop() {
         while(Serial.available()>0 && data != '\n') {    
         data = Serial.read();
         dataIn[count] = data;
         count++;     
      }`                                                                    but the problem continues. @Chris Stratton

Comment: Don't exit when there is no data available, wait for it and only exit (to parsing) on a genuine newline.

Comment: Ah gottcha. I tried this 'void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()>0){
     data = Serial.read();
     dataIn[count] = data;
     count++;
     while(data != '\n') {    
         dataIn[count++] = data;
         count++;                 // count is now equal to the number of relevant elements within the array
     }
  } '

Comment: No, that's still all mixed up and won't work - you'll end up filling memory unbounded with the first non-newline character you receive.

Comment: This worked perfectly 'void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()>0){
     data = Serial.read();
     dataIn[count] = data;
     count++;
     while(data != 13) {    
         data = Serial.read();
         dataIn[count] = data;
         Serial.println(count);
         count++;                 // count is NOT!!!!! equal to the number of relevant elements within the array
         delay(1);
     }
  } ' Thanks! @Chris Stratton    P.s. small delay was necessary to not get read errors

Comment: If you are still using a delay, then no, **you are doing it wrong**.  Proper program logic will not require a delay, and using a delay means **unreliability**.  Edit what you have into your question with indenting and let's get it sorted out.

Comment: @Chris Stratton, yeah youre right it's still screwy. I included the changes I made and some I looked up in the Arduino cookbook.

Comment: @Chris Stratton, I still dont understand why this is giving me an infinitely long array. Any explanation? Perhaps an example? Or reference to one?